# Open New Window And Close Parent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

When my program launches, a window (aka **"StartWindow"**) opens that has 3 options: New Game/Load Game/Exit. When New Game or Load Game is clicked (and after some input), the game window (aka **"GameWindow"**) will open so the user can play.

When the GameWindow opens, I would like to have the StartWindow close. And when the GameWindow closes, the StartWindow will open until the actual "EXIT" button is clicked.

Is there a way to do this? Right now, the only way I can achieve something similar to this is having a boolean called "gameRunning". When this is true, the buttons on StartWindow will have no action when clicked. Opposite when false.

*For example purposes, suppose that each window has 3 buttons, a text field, and nothing else.*

Comment: I would make the StartWindow a JDialog that initially opens with a non-visible JFrame, the GameWindow. Then I'd re-display it as needed.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setVisible(false) method on parent before opening any child window. When child window closes call setVisible(true). It will solve your problem